# How to add / delete a class in Javascript according to Screen Width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've two different menu, one for mobile version and another for pc version. But the menu for mobile version block the menu for pc version. How can resolve that ?

I've already tried to delete the menu for mobile version when I change the screen width in the media queries but this don't work. After I tried to add/delete class in Javascript but they work only for the menu for mobile version, no for the menu for pc version.

```
window.onload = function() {
 overlay();
};

function overlay() {
  let nav = document.getElementById("nav");
  if (document.body.style.width < "991px") {
    nav.classList.add("overlay");
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove("overlay");
  }
};
```

I expect no conflict with the different menus but the menu for pc version don't work unlike the menu for mobile version. And I don't have error messages in the console.

Comment: “document.body.style.width” is a number

Comment: So... “if (document.body.style.width < 991)”

Comment: It's a very bad solution to have two menus and involve JavaScript to remove the "wrong" menu when screen changes. What about when screen changes again? Are you going to add the menu back? The right way to do it is to have a single semantically sound menu element, and use CSS to style it according to available space. I can show you how to do that, but I would be answering a different question then and you'd have to do some research first.

Comment: [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width) would be the better solution.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to explain. It's the same menu with different style.

Answer (score 1):

`document.body.style.width` will only work if and only if you explicitly set the size of the body. You may want to use `screen.width` (or `window.innerWidth` if you want it to work for a resizing window) and then compare.

Example (for easy cut and paste):

```
    window.onload = function() {
     overlay();
    };

    function overlay() {
      let nav = document.getElementById("nav");
      if (window.innerWidth < 991) {
        nav.classList.add("overlay");
      } else {
        nav.classList.remove("overlay");
      }
    };
```

**Links**

- [MDN docs for screen.width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width)
- [MDN docs for window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth)

Answer (score 1):

There it is the answer. Thank you everyone XD.

```js
onload = function() {
  toggleMenus();
}

window.onresize = function() {
  toggleMenus();
}

function toggleMenus() {
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  console.log(width);
  
  if(width < 767) { //mobile
    $(".mobile-menu").show();
    $(".desktop-menu").hide();
  }
  else { //desktop
    $(".mobile-menu").hide();
    $(".desktop-menu").show();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-menu">
  Some mobile menu comtent
</div>

<div class="desktop-menu">
  Some desktop menu content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo() {
   console.log(screen.width, screen.height)
}

window.addEventListener('resize', foo)
```

Then you can remove the wrong class and add the right one

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of achieving this:

**1- CSS media queries:**

```css
/*Mobile*/
@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .mobile-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-menu {
    display: none;
  }
}

/*Desktop*/
@media(min-width: 767px) {
  .mobile-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .desktop-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-menu">
  Some mobile menu comtent
</div>

<div class="desktop-menu">
  Some desktop menu content
</div>
```

**2- Javascript:**

In javascript, you can use `window.innerWidth` to get the window's width, and then show/hide divs accordingly. Don't forget to also perform changes whenever the window is resized:

```js
onload = function() {
  toggleMenus();
}

window.onresize = function() {
  toggleMenus();
}

function toggleMenus() {
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  console.log(width);
  
  if(width < 767) { //mobile
    $(".mobile-menu").show();
    $(".desktop-menu").hide();
  }
  else { //desktop
    $(".mobile-menu").hide();
    $(".desktop-menu").show();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-menu">
  Some mobile menu comtent
</div>

<div class="desktop-menu">
  Some desktop menu content
</div>
```

**3- Bootstrap 4:**

If you don't want to implement your own logic, you can still use Bootstrap 4 classes to show/hide divs based on screen size. For what you want, you can use:

`d-block` with `d-md-none` to hide a div on desktop and show it on mobile

`d-sm-none` with `d-xs-none` and `d-md-block` to hide a div on mobile and show it on desktop.

```
<div class="mobile-menu d-md-none">
  Some mobile menu content
</div>

<div class="desktop-menu d-sm-none d-xs-none d-md-block">
  Some desktop menu content
</div>
```

Comment: @Marion If it works with you, consider marking this as the answer. Glad this helped!